# Data Serialization on Custom DataSourceControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable, xmlserializer, .net-datasourcecontrol

I am writing a custom `DataSourceControl` that will basically have the Select capability working just as a normal `ObjectDataSource`, with a `TypeName` and `SelectMethod` properties.

The Data coming from the TypeName class will be saved in Files indexed by the Hash of the parameter values and a ContextName. Meaning that, everytime a GridView requests the DataSource and the same parameter values are given, the control will find the corresponding File and load the data from there. In fact, every different combination of parameter values will generate a new File with the data.

This functionality could be very helpful in some cases we have when the data takes too long to be processed and retrieved from the database and doesn't need to be live to the user (its always from the last day).

The main difficulty I'm having is to serialize the Data coming from the SelectMethod. As the only thing i know is that the return type will be an instance of `IEnumerable`. I'm using `XMLSerializer` for saving and retrieving the data content from a file, but when trying to serialize it gives me an error `Cannot serialize interface`.

This is the basic code that executes the SelectMethod and does the serialization part:

```
//Gets the select type
Type selectType = Type.GetType(TypeName);

//Gets the select method
MethodInfo selectMethod = selectType.GetMethod(SelectMethod, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

//Creates a new instance of the TypeName class
object selectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(selectType);

//Executes the select method
object selectResult = selectMethod.Invoke(selectInstance, parameters);
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)selectResult;

//Create a serializer
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable));

//Writes to the XML file
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
}
```

I would use this code to deserialize:

```
//Creates the XML File
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable));

IEnumerable list = null;

//Reads from the XML file
using (XmlReader writer = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
{
    list = (IEnumerable) deserializer.Deserialize(writer);
}
```

How can i generically Serialize/Deserialize the Select Method result to XML?

**Update:**

I tried using `System.Web.UI.LosFormatter` to Serialize/Deserialize the data. It did both actions with an IEnumerable instance but i had to put the `Serializable` attribute on the entities. However i noticed a significant difference in performance compared to `XMLSerializer` when retrieving the data from the file. `System.Web.UI.LosFormatter` was 4 times slower at deserializing on my specific test (4MB file). The data file would be half the size compared to the `XMLSerializer` tho. So, for me, `XMLSerializer` still the best option.

**Update2:**

Tried to make a simple test using `ServiceStack JsonSerializer` with the following code:

```
List<Dummy> dummies = new List<Dummy>();

dummies.Add(new Dummy() { Name = "name" });
dummies.Add(new Dummy() { Name = "name1" });
dummies.Add(new Dummy() { Name = "name2" });

IEnumerable enumerableThing = dummies;

string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "data2.json");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    JsonSerializer.SerializeToWriter<IEnumerable>(enumerableThing, writer);
}

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    enumerableThing = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<IEnumerable>(reader);
}
```

It does work serializing, but when trying to DeserializeFromReader, it gives me the error `"Type System.Collections.IEnumerable is not of type IDictionary<,>"`.
Is there any way i could make this work?

Comment: Since you're working in the ASP.NET context, you could use the LosFormatter instead of XmlSerializer (if you don't need the data to be human readable). The advantage is it's pretty automatic and "web-aware", plus the supported types are consistent with Web Controls properties. see here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/13/LosFormatter-for-easy-Serialization

Comment: @ Simon Mourier, Thanks for the comment, updated the answer with content related to the LosFormatter.

Comment: I think the reason why XmlSerializer is faster is because the Xml serialization is compiled automatically in a temp assembly, and incidentally, that's why it's not very flexible/automatic/versatile.

Comment: I tried using BinaryFormatter as well, both performed worse than XMlSerializer on a test here.

Comment: Yep, same reason, BinaryFormatter is not compiled. You could try servicestack's Json serializer which I believe is fast: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

Comment: Thanks @ Simon Mourier, I'll try it. I've tried Protobuf-net, it  needs attributes on the entity classes and the type when serializing/deserializing, but the performance and file size were great tho.

Comment: Added an update to the answer related to the ServiceStack's Json serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you've already discovered, you can't serialize an interface...that said, you might be able to work around this and still be "in the dark" about the actual object types:

First, any IEnumerable can be transmogrified into an array via a `Cast`/`ToArray` combo

```
var enumerableThing = Foo.GetEnumerable();    
var asArray = enumerableThing.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Second, Arrays of a "known type" *are* Serializable

```
var allContainedTypes = asArray.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().ToArray();
var ser = new XmlSerializer(asArray.GetType(), allContainedTypes);
```

<strike>var ser = new XmlSerializer(asArray.GetType());</strike>

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using(var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    ser.Serialize(xw, asArray);

sb.ToString().Dump();
```

Or, all together:

```
void Main()
{
    var enumerableThing = Foo.GetEnumerable();    
    var asArray = enumerableThing.Cast<object>().ToArray();

    var allContainedTypes = asArray.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().ToArray();
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(asArray.GetType(), allContainedTypes);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using(var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
        ser.Serialize(xw, asArray);

    sb.ToString().Dump();
}


public class Foo
{
    public static IEnumerable GetEnumerable()
    {
        return new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    }
    public static IEnumerable GetEnumerable2()
    {
        return new object[] { "1", 2, "bob", 4, null, 6, 7 };
    }
}
```

Oh, this produces the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfAnyType 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">3</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">4</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">5</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">6</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">7</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Edit: Deserialization does pose some problems - however, you can do something akin to:

```
// Least common denominator...
object[] tempResult;

var assemblyStuffIsFrom = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var allSerializableTypes = assemblyStuffIsFrom
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true).Any())
    // TODO: add as much filtering as you can here to help trim down the set
    .ToArray();
var hope = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object[]), allSerializableTypes);
using(var sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    tempResult = ((object[])hope.Deserialize(xr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code, but inside the `GetEnumerable` method i returned a `List<Dummy>`, `Dummy` being some test class with a Name property only. It returned the error `The type WebApp.Page+Dummy was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically` on the `ser.Serialize` line. You see, i just did that to simulate a common context we have.

Comment: Ah, yes, almost forgot - I used the wrong overload of the `XmlSerializer` - I'll edit the answer.  @Mt.Schneiders Ok, try that version.

Comment: Thanks @JerKimball. Can you show me the code to deserialize the XML data? Because i wouldn't have the `allContainedTypes` when trying to retrieve the data, assuming the `DataSourceControl` itself verifies the XML existence before calling the `SelectMethod`.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Would you know what assembly the contained types are defined within?

Comment: @ JerKimball: Yes, in the current project. But this solution could be ported to other projects afterwards, so, the less inner dependencies the better. Actually in the current solution we have several projects, the DataSourceControl will remain at the WebApplication project where it's TypeName will stay on a Business Object project. Will `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` resolve the types on all the projects assemblies?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders No, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` is what I used in my little test harness - that's the one line you'd have to change to suit your actual environment.

Comment: @ JerKimball Thanks, i see it could be a possible solution, but as it is a generic control it won't really be easily aware of the environment tho.

Comment: Well, good luck to you - without some hardcore reflection or introspection, I don't see how you'd be able to generically infer what type a given xml blob is...that's the one caveat with serialization: you kinda need to know what "shape" you're trying to reconstitute on the other end.